# Why does this only work once?

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to put together a simple feedback form which uses PHP to email the results to us. The script works once, we get the email as intended.. but every time afterwards, there's no email and no error. Anyone have any idea why?

```
    <?php


$email_to = "admin@urbansushi.com";

$name = $_POST['name']; // required

$email = $_POST['email']; // required

$date = $_POST['date']; // required

$email_subject = "New feedback from CUSTOMER";






$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";

$email_message .= "Date of Visit: ".clean_string($date)."\n";

$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";

    // create email headers


$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  


?>
```

Comment: If you take of that `@` is there an error on the `mail` function?

Comment: @chris85 nope, no error but also no change in the result.

Comment: @TimKaye you said it works only once. What event resets it so it can work (again) only once?

Comment: @BeetleJuice Last week when I started on this, it would work again once I reuploaded the php file to the host. Today I haven't been able to get it to work again.. It worked twice in a row and then nothing I've tried has gotten it to work again.

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating to $email_message but are not  declaring it initially:

```
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
```

Try adding this

```
$email_message = "";
$email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
```

also you have whitespace before your php declaration - try removing it so that the php declaration is at the start of the file

`<?php`

Comment: No change. Also, there's a success message that sits outside the php code which isn't showing either.

Comment: `code` $headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
 
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
 
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

 
?>
 
 
 
<!-- include your own success html here -->
 
 
 
Thank you for your feedback! you will now be redirected to the Urban Sushi website.
 
 
 

</body>
</html>